# Extract winner/-s in survey, then print

Tags: c, arrays

I've been tasked with writing a section of a voting program.

The user inputs as command line arguments the names of contestants (up to a max of 9), the program then asks for the number of voters, and then asks which of the contestants each voter voted for.

My job is to finish the two sections below, that will extract the highest number of votes received by anyone, and then in the second section print all those contestants who have that highest vote. If only one contestant has that high score, it prints that name. If it's a tie between two or more contestants, it prints the names of all those contestants.

In the main section, there is a struct called contestant, that has the name of the contestant as a string, and the number of votes as an integer.

I'm a true novice, and am struggling, as you can tell right away when looking at the code.

Here is one important disclaimer:
- I'm not allowed to change any of the rest of the program, beyond adding includes.

```
bool count(string name)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < contestant_count; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(name, contestant[i].name) == 0)
        {
            contestant[i].votes++;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

void display_highest(void)
{
    int max = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= contestant_count -1; i++)
    {
        if (contestant[i].votes == max)
        {
            max = display_highest;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= contestant_count -1; i++)
    {
        if (contestant[i].votes ==  display_highest)
        printf("%s \n", contestant[i].name);
    }
    return;
}
```

The function `display_highest()` is not established in the main program, so I can't use it. But I'm trying to find a way to extract the highest vote count, so that I can then tell the program separately to print anyone with that vote count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit hard to understand what you want to achieve here, so if you think I misunderstood something please don't hesitate to correct me.

**Firstly**, I will assume that your `string` variable is something like a `const char*` since there aren't any `string` type in C. (at least I do not know of any) 
**Secondly**, I will assume that your `contestant` and `contestant_count` variables are some global variables. 
**And lastly**, I will assume that you use the `count(string name)` function to add votes to the contestant with the name of `name`.

Now that, that's out of the way I think your only problem lies within the function `display_highest()`.

```
void display_highest(void)
{
    // Here we find the maximum vote number
    int max = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < contestant_count; i++)
    {
        // if the maximum is less than the votes
        // then update the max variable
        if (contestant[i].votes > max)
        {
            max = contestant[i].votes;
        }
    }
    // Here we display all, who has the maximum vote number
    for (int i = 0; i < contestant_count; i++)
    {
        // display contestants with 'max' vote number
        if (contestant[i].votes == max)
        {
            printf("%s \n", contestant[i].name);
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

Maybe this is the answer you're looking for, but then again, if I misunderstood something feel free to correct me.